# Random characters being deleted from paragraph element after hovering over them

Tags: javascript, hover, event-listener

I have two paragraphs that are comprised of 8 rows that each contain 12 characters. The characters are either random symbols or full words whose positions are random. My code is supposed to highlight individual characters if they are symbols or highlight the full word when the mouse is hovering over them.

My plan was to wrap the characters with spans and add listeners to them that will be able to highlight them when a hover event is occuring. While this works (symbols are being highlighted, words are being highlighted) when I move my cursor around characters are randomly dissapearing.

[Here is what it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owx6w.png)
[Here is what happens after I move my cursor around the right paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaCO0.png)

Entirety of code: https://codepen.io/somecoder21/pen/BavROJX

Here is the code the relevant code

```
const garbage = ["`", "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "-", "_", "=", "+"];
const wordBank = ["jujube", "muzzle", "puzzle", "whizzo", " jimply", "jinxed", " fezzes", "queazy"];
const numOfRows = 8;

const password = wordBank[randomNum(0, wordBank.length)];

function fillText() {
    fillParagraph("left-p");
    fillParagraph("right-p");
}

function fillParagraph(pId) {
    let string = "";
    let wordPos = [];
    let counter = 0;

    //find valid word positions
    for (let i = 0; i < (wordBank.length); i++) {
        let validPos = false;
        while (!validPos) {
            validPos = true;
            const randomNumber = randomNum(0, (12 * numOfRows) - 6);
            for (let j = 0; j < wordPos.length; j++) {
                if ((randomNumber >= (wordPos[j] - 6)) && (randomNumber <= (wordPos[j] + 6))) {
                    validPos = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (validPos) {
                wordPos.push(randomNumber);
            }
        }
        if (counter === 3) {
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    //add the words to the random locations and make sure they do not go over 12 characters per row
    for (let i = 0; i < (numOfRows * 12); i++) {
        if (i % 12 === 0 && i !== 0) {
            string += "\n";
        }

        let counter = 0;

        if (wordPos.includes(i)) {
            for (let j = 0; j < wordBank[0].length; j++) {
                if (i % 12 === 0 && i !== 0 && j !== 0) {
                    string += "\n";
                }

                string += wordBank[0].charAt(j);
                i++;
            }
            wordBank.shift()
            if (i % 12 === 0 && i !== 0) {
                string += "\n";
            }
            counter++;
        }
        string += garbage[randomNum(0, garbage.length - 1)];
    }

    const paragraph = document.getElementById(pId);
    paragraph.setAttribute('style', 'white-space: pre;')
    paragraph.textContent = string;
}

function randomNum(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function highlight(event) {
    const text = event.target.textContent;
    const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]$/;
    const tempArray = [];
    const characters = text.split("");

    //surround individual characters or words with spans
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        const char = characters[i];
        //wrap whole word
        if(regex.test(char)) {
            let word = "";
            for(let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                word += characters[i];
                i++;
            }
            tempArray.push(`<span class='chars'>${word}</span>`);
            continue;
        }
        //wrap individual character
        tempArray.push(`<span class='chars'>${char}</span>`);
    }

    event.target.innerHTML = tempArray.join("");

    let spans = event.target.querySelectorAll(`.chars`);
    console.log(spans)
    spans.forEach((span) => {
        span.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            // Add the yellow background color to the currently hovered character
            span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        });

        span.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
            // Remove the background color when the mouse leaves
            span.style.backgroundColor = "";
        });
    });
}

function functionality() {
    const elementL = document.getElementById("left-p");
    elementL.addEventListener("mouseover", highlight);
    const elementR = document.getElementById("right-p");
    elementR.addEventListener("mouseover", highlight);
}

fillText()
functionality();
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Please provide a working CodePen or a CodeSnippet. Then it would be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @stax Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the code pen: https://codepen.io/somecoder21/pen/BavROJX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are firing the Hightlight function everytime you hover over one of the divs, and when highlight happens it basically goes through the text and if it matches the regex(the first aplha char) and wraps a few chars ahead in a span and updates the page with only those spanned elements. Basically, due to how the regex is matching and how you walk through the individual characters even if the first matches, you are loosing special chars everytime you mouse over. notice after you hover a bunch it ends up only being a-zA-Z characters.

I think this will be a lot simplier if you just sort things out when you build the initial display, and then let css handle the hovering rather than trying to do it all with hover events.

My example doesn't do all the randomizing yours does, but its just a stripped down example to show how it might work. if you need conditional logic based on the contents of the span, you can do that when you go through the for loop.

```js
const wordBank = ["jujube", "muzzle", "puzzle", "whizzo", " jimply", "jinxed", " fezzes", "queazy"];
const garbage = ["`", "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "-", "_", "=", "+"];
let txtOutput = '';

function fillText() {
  let temp = wordBank.concat(garbage);
  for( let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    //if element matches regex do : 
    txtOutput += '<span class="char">' + temp[Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length)] + '</span>';
    //else do something else
  }
  document.querySelector("#myDiv").innerHTML = txtOutput;
}

fillText();
```

```css
.char:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I still don't entirely understand why my approach doesn't seem to work since each word should be captured without deleting any of the other ones. But I am going to follow your advice by wrapping the characters and words in a span as soon as I have their positions and then just use CSS for the highlighting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok now with fresh eyes, I sort of see the error more clearly. When your regex matches it does a for loop six times and adds that offset to the i index to account for the rest of the word you know is 6 characters long. However because of the for loop, it adds another to i effectively skipping over the next character after the word regardless of what it is which removes it from the display. I think its also getting confused on newlines somehow and eventually I think the index gets thrown off and you end up with the index being outside the bounds of the array and you'll see undefined pop up.

Comment: maybe try this [link](https://codepen.io/nullbody/full/YzdVMVv). instead we are working through it normally, and just building the word. this way we also don't care how long the word is.

Comment: technically I think in my example if two words go back to back they will be wrapped together. If you really want to enforce that a word is always 6 char, you could use same logic in my link, but kind of like how I build the word and reset it, you could make a counter that increments as it builds the word and if the counter reaches the length of the word (6) it wraps it and resets the word and counter.

Comment: However at the end of the day, If you are receiving the words and special char in separate arrays like you are now, its kind of redundant to parse it after when you already know the difference. So if you can find a different way to build the display, where as you build it you know which is which based on the arrays they are coming from, there is no need to parse it after.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it makes a lot more sense to me now. I also agree with your comments about the parsing redundency. In my new approach I am going to just take out the highlight function and basically do everything in the fillParagraph.

Comment: [like so](https://codepen.io/somecoder21/pen/BavZBeZ). Although this is creating some formatting issues that I need to resolve but I think it is much cleaner and follows your advice of just using the css hover.